# assign a char array to the other which is also a argument of function in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, parameter-passing

I run this code and get console shutdown every time.

could you help me? thank you

```
int lower(int a) 
{
    if ((a >= 0x41) && (a <= 0x5A))
        a |= 0x20; 
    return a;  
}
void get_lower_case(char** str)
{
    int str_len = strlen(*str);
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(str_len);

    while (**str)
    {
        *temp =lower(**str);
        temp++;
        *str++;
    }
    strncpy( *str, temp, str_len);
    free(temp);
}
int main()
{
char searchChars[] = "findstring";
get_lower_case(&searchChars);

return (0);
}
```

or there is any other way that I can change char array as argument?

Comment: What do you mean by `get console shutdown every time` ?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting/ line num?

Comment: Why are you passing `&searchChars`?, just pass `searchChars` and change the prototype to `void get_lower_case(char *str)` (and adjust the references within). No need to `strncpy` anything.

Comment: There's no reason why you need to allocate and free memory; you can change each character in situ.

Comment: note that `temp`(and `str`) has changed since the while-loop.

Comment: Are you on Windows, using Visual Studio?

Comment: get console shutdown every time => means crush when i run it.
I use dev-c++ 5.11 . thank you

Comment: [fix your approach](https://ideone.com/DLJwQx)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you , I got it ! you are so kind.

Comment: regarding: `char *temp = (char *)malloc(str_len);`  1) the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone when performing debug or maintenance.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the function: `strlen()` returns the index to the trailing NUL byte, and indexes start with 0 so have to add 1 to the call to `malloc()` to have enough room for the source string.

Comment: this loop: `while (**str)
    {
        *temp =lower(**str);
        temp++;
        *str++;
    }` is a very bad idea.  Strongly suggest: `for( int i=0; (*str)[i]; i++ ) { temp[i] = lower( (*str)[i] );`

Comment: rather than writing a function: `lower()`,  much better to use: `#include <ctype.h> ...  temp[i] = tolower( (*str)[i] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, there is no need to pass a *pointer to pointer to char* to `get_lower_case`. You have a modifiable string in `searchChars`, so simply pass the string and operate on the characters within it. You will greatly simply your conversion to lower case.

Also, don't use magic numbers in your code, e.g. `(a >= 0x41) && (a <= 0x5A)`, `(a >= 'A') && (a <= 'Z')` is much easier to read. You can keep `0x20` as `32`.

Putting the pieces together,  you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lower(int a) 
{
    if ((a >= 'A') && (a <= 'Z'))
        a |= 0x20;
    return a;  
}

void get_lower_case (char *str)
{
    while (*str) {
        *str = lower(*str);
        str++;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    char searchChars[] = "FINDstring";
    get_lower_case(searchChars);
    printf ("%s\n", searchChars);

    return (0);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tolower
findstring
```

Comment: why when I use char* it wasn't worked?    
  search_str_in_file((char*)"test.txt", (char*)"FindTag");void search_str_in_file(char *fname, char* sub){get_lower_case(sub);}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `while` loop and the logic that is written to copy the string from source to destination.

```
while (**str)
{
    *temp =lower(**str);
    temp++; //pointer is moved to next location of memory
    *str++; //pointer is moved to next location of memory
}
strncpy( *str, temp, str_len); //at this point both pointers are pointing to the end of the string
free(temp); //pointer is pointing to the end of the memory
```

In the `while` loop both the pointers are incremented to next location of memory and at the end of that loop both will point to the end of the string, the next statement is `strncpy()` and `free()` which is obviously going to fail as `strncpy` will copy garbage value to `str` and `temp` has moved to end so call to `free` will also fail.

The best solution is the above one that @David C. Rankin has suggested or an alternative is, you can take two more pointers to point to `temp` and `str` at the beginning of the function `get_lower_case()` and use those two pointers to copy the string.

Comment: thank you for completely explaining about how pointer works while loop move on. I learned a lot.